# Using Suds with PHP SoapServer

Tags: python, soap, suds

Is it possible to use consume a SOAP Webservice (written in PHP) without WSDL via python-suds?

Scenario is, I have a simple PHP SoapServer with one function exposed, now I need to access this service via Python. Since PHP's own SoapServer doesn't generate a WSDL I have to use it without the presence of such a file.

Is this possible, if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know suds requires a WSDL for operation. One way to solve that problem is to write a WSDL manually which is a bit tedious but doable for simple services.

Alternatively you could use a library which does not rely on a WSDL. I contributed to such a library named [soapfish](http://www.soapfish.org). One downside of soapfish is that there is almost no documentation and the built-in code generation (from WSDL) often provides a good starting point but again, for a simple service it is usually not much work to build the object graph manually.